# Generic touchpad driver w/ scrolling

Tags: windows-7, drivers, touchpad

Does anyone know of a generic driver for touchpads that supports scrolling.  I specifically need this for a Windows 7 machine but could use it on others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Most touchpads would originate with Synaptics, and at worst would be just rebadged.  I've used their driver on a wide variety of different makes and models (and OS versions) with success.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a thing exists.  Windows drivers are written to support hardware with a given set of Plug'n'Play IDs.  Vendors who provide "universal" drivers are just including all of the PnP IDs for their hardware in a single driver file or including multiple driver files in a single package.  Trying to find a driver that supports any old touchpad regardless of the vendor who made it is going to be basically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Touchpad using the generic "PS/2 Compatible Mouse" driver sometimes works. On my XP laptop, it gave me tracking and scrolling: just what I wanted. On another laptop running Win7 however, scrolling wouldn't work, so your results may vary.

Answer (score 0):

If your touchpad is Synaptics, I think they've released multi-touch drivers, at least according to [this](http://www.engadget.com/2010/03/19/synaptics-driver-enables-multitouch-gestures-on-older-trackpads/).

This should allow some mac-like configuration (i.e. 2 fingers will scroll, etc).  Unfortunately, I can't find a link to the driver.